# How to collect user opinions about software

Tags: c#, winforms, email, social-networking

I have written a small .net Windows Forms application. And now I decided to get opinions or comments from users. User will just write something in a input form and click a send button.

I want to use the most easiest way. I don't want to host any webservices or another applications for gathering the information. Also I don't have a database. Nothing. I just want to know what people think about the application.

How would you do it?

Comment: on click of the send button mail the content with same subject for all the comments. Have filter option in your inbox to segregate them to single label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW if you do go with the answers suggesting to just call out to a SMTP server remember that any application you develop in .NET if you don't use some sort of security packaging framework all of the text that is stored inside the application is essentially the same as a text file. So if you embed your smtp server credentials inside your application it could be very easy to have them stolen.

I think the simplest solution for you would be to just put a hyperlink in your application to mailto:your@address.com?Subject=txtSubject.Text&Body=txtBody.Text and then let the users system handle the mailto operation by its default handler.

Comment: @Chris: This will take the user outside of the application, and requires that they have a valid mail account configured on their `mailto:` client.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I intended. This is an operation that should be client controlled.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be to send an email. Check out the [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

On Click of the submit button **e-mail** the text in the input box to yourself.

How to do it is [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c).(**Sending e-mail using GMAIL smtp server C#**)

And then using [**Textual Sentiment Analysis**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573768/sentiment-analysis-for-twitter-in-python) you can know what people think about your software.Take a look at [**twittersentiments**](http://twittersentiment.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably an email will be intercepted by antivirus, firewall, you name it. Besides, I would not be surprised if an ugly MessageBox shows up (this application is tryng to send an email...).
Worse yet, odd are, if an antivirus intercepts the email, not you not the user will never know.

So, I would go with mailto link, as Cris Marisic suggest.