# Looking for open source naive Bayesian Classifier in C# for a Twitter sentiment analysis project

Tags: c#, twitter, bayesian, classification

I've found a similar project here: [Sentiment analysis for Twitter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573768/sentiment-analysis-for-twitter-in-python) . However, I'm working on C# and need to use a naive Bayesian Classifier that is open source in the same language. Unless someone can shed light on how I can utilize a python Bayesian Classifier to achieve the same goals. Any ideas?

Comment: You could go the out of process route to access the Python library - not pretty - but something.  (You could also look into IronPython as a possibility.)

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used the code from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BayesClassifier.aspx) CodeProject article in a project a few years ago and it's still working beautifully with ~99% accuracy.

Comment: How did you use that Bayesian classifier? I'm following the instructions but a little loss.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't strictly need naive Bayes, I would suggest libshogun. It has a huge number of high-quality classifiers, and it apparently has been successfully built for win32 on cygwin. After that's built you can just p/invoke to the DLLs from C#. I think you will find it difficult to find a classifier library written in C# due to the often performance-heavy nature of classification, so your best bet is to call a native library such as this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something to look at:

https://github.com/joelmartinez/nBayes

https://github.com/joelmartinez/nBayes/wiki