# perform classifier training on twitter data

Tags: java, twitter, nlp

I have just started learning about NLP and I have to do a course project this semester. what I want to do is :
a.) Fetch the tweets from twitter for a particular topic ( How can I do that?? )

b.) Have already trained data against which I can decide if the tweets I fetched has positive or negative sentiment ( how to train this data )

c.) show the results to user

I want to use Java for this, and I found that we can use [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/index.html) for this

I am all new to this and building the app for the first time, so guidance is very much appreciated

Comment: This is not a site for guidance, this site is for questions. And I don't see any in your post.

Comment: "How" marks a question in English.

Comment: Oh, you're a joker, aren't you? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twitter APIs for Java](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#java)

A survey text on [opinion mining and sentiment analysis](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/opinion-mining-sentiment-analysis-survey.html), which is what you're looking to do. I've actually read portions of this text, and thought it was decent. It isn't a "here's an algorithm to analyze twitter" book (perhaps [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321)?), but it'll have references to bajillions of research papers in the area, from which you should be able to find algorithms and analysis.

Also, the question "[Sentiment Analysis for Twitter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573768/sentiment-analysis-for-twitter-in-python)" is going to be helpful to you, as well.

Your questions are vague, so, sorry, you get somewhat vague answers.

Answer (score 2):

The Collective Intelligence book mentioned by Jay is worth a look.

If you follow his Python hint, then you really need to look at the NLTK toolkit, which is intended for teaching.